# Django REST serializer error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm defining model serializers to POST a task instance in Django REST.

My models are:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    """
    Model instance represents basic info about calculations doing in Celery worker.
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)

class Vector(models.Model):
    """
    Model instance represents geometry file (*.SHP) saved in FileSystem.
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    file_path = models.CharField()

class CalculateVector(models.Model):
    """
    Model instance represents neccessary info for call Celery worker task.
    It contains 1:M relation between Vector and CalculateVector. 
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task_id = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='calculate_vectors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    method = models.CharField()
    vector = models.ForeignKey(Vector, models.SET_NULL, related_name='vector')
```

so each CalculateVector instance has info about only one Vector model instance, but Vector model can contain several CalculateVector instances.

and my serializers are:

```
class VectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Vector
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name'
        )


class CalculateVectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    vector = VectorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CalculateVector
        fields = (
            'id',
            'method',
            'vector'
        )

class CreateTaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    calculate_vectors = CalculateVectorSerializer()

    class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'calculate_vectors'
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):

        calculate_vector_data = validated_data.pop('calculate_vectors')
        instance = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)

        vector = Vector.objects.get(id=calculate_vector_data.get('vector')['id'])
        CalculateVector.objects.update_or_create(
            task_id=instance,
            method=calculate_vector_data['method'],
            vector=vector,
        )

        return instance
```

when tried to query this serializer I received an error using:

```
>>> data = {'name':'test task','description':'description','calculate_vectors':{'vector':{'id':1,'name':'calc1'},'method':'method1'}}
>>> serializer = CreateTaskSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
>>> serializer.save()
>>> serializer.data

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `vector` on serializer `CalculateVectorSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'vector'.
```

Why I can not use `serializer.data` variable? And how can I fix that? Any help?

Comment: @HåkenLid Fixed.

Comment: Your naming is rather confusing to me. What do the classes `Vector` and `CalculateVector` represent? Why is the relation called `vector` in both directions? Docstrings and comments would really help explain what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @HåkenLid See added model docstrings. Relation called ```vector``` in both directions was created after received error from the question in hope that it will solve my problem - but it didn't.

Comment: Do you have a full traceback for this error?

Comment: I don't know exactly why you get this error. But it looks like Task and Vector has a relation through CalcaluteVector. There's an ideomatic way to do this in django. Check out the [example from the docs of using `through` relations.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields). (also, you don't need to explicitly set an `id` field for your models, since django models will have a primary key autofield by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calculate_vectors` is `RelatedManager` and return list of objects, you should add `many=True` argument into `CreateTaskSerializer`:

```
class CreateTaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    calculate_vectors = CalculateVectorSerializer(many=True)
```

Also in `create()` method `validated_data.pop('calculate_vectors')` will return list, so you need to iterate over it:

```
 def create(self, validated_data):

    calculate_vector_data = validated_data.pop('calculate_vectors')
    instance = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for vector_data in calculate_vector_data:    
        vector = Vector.objects.get(id=vector_data.get('vector')['id'])
        CalculateVector.objects.update_or_create(
        task_id=instance,
        method=vector_data['method'],
        vector=vector,
        )
```

And when you POST data it also should be list in JSON:

```
"calculate_vectors": [{"somedata"}, {"somedata"}]
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it works quite alright :) but is there any possibility to POST a dict, not a list of dicts, in "calculate_vectors" field, because the request should contains info about only one caltulating vector more likely in that way: "calculate_vectors": {'method': 'some_method', 'vector':{'id': 1, 'name': 'some_name'}} ?

Comment: @sorryMike for this you need to use `onetoonefield` instead of `ForeignKey` in `CalculateVector` model:  `task_id = models.OneToOneField(Task, related_name='calculate_vectors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

Comment: I understand. So in my problem list limited to one dict object will fit. Thanks for the clarification.